# Is "Del" a reserved keyword in Powershell?

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I am calling the "Del" function in Main and was asking me to delete the folder. When I renamed to "Delete" it works fine as I expected. Just wondering if the "Del" is a reserved keyword in PS.

Codes:

```
function Main {
  #Delete the entire folder instead going into Del function
  Del $Path
}

function Del ($DropLocation) {
  # code...
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Del is not a keyword, but it is an alias to the cmdlet `Remove-Item`. According to documentation at (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849765.aspx), the following commands are aliased to the same cmdlet:

- del
- erase
- rd
- ri
- rm
- rmdir

If you execute the command `Get-Help about_Language_Keywords`, you see the following reserved words.

```
Keyword            Reference
-------            ---------
Begin              about_Functions, about_Functions_Advanced
Break              about_Break, about_Trap
Catch              about_Try_Catch_Finally
Continue           about_Continue, about_Trap
Data               about_Data_Sections
Do                 about_Do, about_While 
Dynamicparam       about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters
Else               about_If 
Elseif             about_If 
End                about_Functions, about_Functions_Advanced_Methods
Exit               Described in this topic.
Filter             about_Functions
Finally            about_Try_Catch_Finally
For                about_For
Foreach            about_Foreach
From               Reserved for future use.
Function           about_Functions, about_Functions_Advanced
If                 about_If
In                 about_Foreach
Param              about_Functions
Process            about_Functions, about_Functions_Advanced
Return             about_Return
Switch             about_Switch
Throw              about_Throw, about_Functions_Advanced_Methods
Trap               about_Trap, about_Break, about_Try_Catch_Finally
Try                about_Try_Catch_Finally
Until              about_Do
While              about_While, about_Do
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can also use Get-Alias to see all the currently reserved aliases.